# How can I convert distance from one location to another in miles swift?

Tags: swift, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I have 2 coordinates - coordinate consisting of long and lat which is one location and coordinate b which is another location. How do I correctly convert to two distances into miles - for example, I want it to display 2.3 miles away based on my calculation. I think my calculation may be wrong, as I am getting values like 2339.32? Am I not rounding off correctly or is my calculation wrong?

```swift
let userCoordinates = CLLocation(latitude: userLatitude, longitude: userLongitude)
let locationCoordinates = CLLocation(latitude: locationLatitude, longitude: 
      locationLongitude)

let distanceInMeters = userCoordinates.distance(from: locationCoordinates) // gets the distance from both locations.

let miles = distanceInMeters * 0.62137
```

Comment: If your initial distance is in metres then you need to multiply by 0.000621371 to get the number of miles. If your converting kilometres to miles you multiply by 0.621371

Comment: yes that is correct thanks, i was using a wrong calculation to convert metres to miles.

Comment: Better to use Swift Measurement type to convert your units